# Java command not recognized by cmd if not run as admin

Tags: java

In windows 10 I installed Java 13 and updated the path variables. One strange thing I see is java command is not recognized until I run cmd as admin. Any idea why this happens? Do I need to change any settings

Comment: Sounds like you need to add the installation directory to your PATH environment variable as a regular user - my guess is you only changed the environment variable for the admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you installed java into the folder that can be accessed only by administrator. Thave to installed java on this path `C:\WINDOWS\system32; C:\WINDOWS; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin`
now it will be recongnized by all users.

BTW: for me Java 8 is better choice than Java 13